# Bootstrap 4 - Grid problem - It doesn't start a new row where I would expect it to

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am trying to create this:

[image]

This is unfortunately what I get:

[image]

I am using PHP and Bootstrap 4. This is my script:

```
<div class="row"> <!-- row -->

<div class="col-md-9"> <!-- left part of page -->
  <div class="row">

    <div class="panel panel-purple title">
        The Blog Title is Here
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-purple title">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3">
            My image file goes here
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-9">
            A lot of text about the log
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>

  </div> <!-- end of row -->
 </div> <!-- end of left part of page -->

 <div class="col-md-3"> <!-- right part of page -->
   <div class="panel panel-purple">This is where the blog archive list will go.  You can click on Year and then Month to see the blogs</div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working snippet: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OdNxyK

In Bootstrap 4 a `row` is a **flex** element, inside that element, you can simply just make 2 columns with your specified widths and add additional divs inside them which will take the whole width of their container.

I added a row inside the **col-9** and **col-3** because the container of the additional 100% wide cols needs to be flex in order to work properly, and also, the minus margins will nullify the cols additional paddings. Also your `panel` classes will behaviour as block elements again, because their container won't be `flex`

An additional plus is that, the two cols inside the main row will be the same height, no matter of their content, in this case, if you would like only one custom element with background in your col on the right, you just give it `height: 100%` and it will be always as high as your left column.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-9">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12"></div>
            <div class="col-12"></div>
            <div class="col-12"></div>
            <div class="col-12"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```html
<div class="row"> <!-- row -->
  <div class="col-md-9"> <!-- left part of page -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="panel panel-purple title">
          The Blog Title is Here
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-purple title">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
              My image file goes here
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
              A lot of text about the log
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- end of row -->
  </div> <!-- end of left part of page -->

   <div class="col-md-3"> <!-- right part of page -->
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="panel panel-purple">This is where the blog archive list will go.  You can click on Year and then Month to see the blogs</div>
      </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you!  I think I understand now and my html is working.